# A question about progressive sound waves

Tags: waves, acoustics

I know the value of $s(x,t)$ in a given pair $(x,t)$, how do I know the value of the pressure variation in this same pair $(x,t)$? Knowing the maximum displacement $(s_m)$, the speed of sound in this fluid, and the maximum pressure $(\Delta P_m)$, the only things I don't know are the coefficients $k$ and $\omega$.

my thought: i tried something with the relations $\Delta P_m=(v\rho \omega)s_m$ and $\Delta P_m=(v^2\rho k)s_m$ to try to find $\omega$ and $k$, but it always depends on $\rho$, so it doesn't fit when I try to put it in the equation $\Delta P=\Delta P_msin(kx-\omega t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only given a numerical value of $s$ at an instant, then use:
$$\frac{s}{s_{max}} = \text{cos}(kx - wt)$$ and find $|\text{sin} (kx - wt)|$, using the identity $\text{sin}^2(A) + \text{cos}^2(A) = 1 \ ∀ A \ ∈ R$, and then substitute it in the equation of the variation in pressure: $$∆P = ∆P_{max} \text{sin}(kx - wt)$$

---

Else, if you have been provided with the equation of the position in terms of some $x$ and $t$, then using $$∆P_{max} = Bs_{max}k$$ you can find the value of the term $Bk = \frac{∆P_{max}}{s_{max}}$ and then the variation in pressure can be found from the equation: $$∆P = -B .\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, it helped me a lot, thanks, I hadn't thought of using the trigonometric identity.